# Java NullPointerException on serialization of TableModel when associated JTable is on visible JFrame

Tags: java, serialization, nullpointerexception, jtable, tablemodel

A NullPointerException is thrown when trying to serialize a TableModel object while the associated JTable object is visible in a JFrame. I created a minimal, reproducible Example and will also include the Stack-Trace.

The Nullpointer is described like this:

```
Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JTable.getColumnModel()" 
because "this.table" is null
```

But why is this method called anyway? I am serializing the Model, not the JTable.

When not using a JFrame, it works fine.

I hope someone can help. I am using AdoptOpenJDK14 (14.0.2.12-hotspot)

Here is the minimal, reproducible Example:

Serialization.java (Entrypoint of the Program)

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Serialization {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MyAbstractModel model = new MyAbstractModel();
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        // After creating the frame, putting in the table and setting it to visible the exception will be thrown when trying to serialize below
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(table);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("some.dat"));
        oos.writeObject(model);
        oos.close();

    }
}
```

MyAbstractModel.java (The Model to Serialize)

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MyAbstractModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAbstractModel(){
        list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        list.add("Test1");
        list.add("Test2");
        list.add("Test3");
        list.add("Test4");
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return rowIndex + "-" + columnIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return "Column " + column;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Some.java (Just a Serializable Test Object)

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Some implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final int num;
    public final String name;
    transient int ignoreNum;

    public Some(int num, String name, int ignoreNum) {
        this.num = num;
        this.name = name;
        this.ignoreNum = ignoreNum;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Some{" +
                "num=" + num +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", ignoreNum=" + ignoreNum +
                '}';
    }

}
```

This is the Stacktrace I got.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JTable.getColumnModel()"
> because "this.table" is null
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTableUI.java:1768)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1680)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.setWidthsFromPreferredWidths(JTable.java:3205)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.doLayout(JTable.java:3117)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1722)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1657)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JTable.getColumnModel()" because "this.table" is null
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTableUI.java:1768)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1680)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.setWidthsFromPreferredWidths(JTable.java:3205)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.doLayout(JTable.java:3117)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1722)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1657)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: The exception does not ssem to be related to serialization on the first glance - does it also throw if you remove the serialization part (i.e. don't write to the OOS)? Try to just set the prefered size on the JFrame, as it seems that this is thrown while deriving the prefered size from the components.

Comment: Only happens on serialization. Without it, it works. @Hulk

Comment: fwiw your code runs fine for me

Comment: Ok, this shocked me but I also got it working by adding a sleep of 1 second before serializing, BUT STILL, why this behavior? From the stack trace, I think there is some event stuff going around but I don't know what it could be and why...

Comment: All Swing component should be create on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Otherwise you can get random behaviour. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.